# Remove " from a file using Perl script

Tags: regex, perl, unix

I have a sample file like this

```
001|"Arab"|hjgjk
002|"HGJ"|dkflj
```

i need the output like

```
001|Arab|hjgjk
002|HGJ|dkflj
```

i have tried below code

```
perl -pi -e 's/\"//g' file1 > file2
```

Please help

Comment: Do you need to do this with perl?  It can certainly be done with perl, but perl really isn't the right tool.  There's no need to limit yourself by being too specific in the question.

Comment: He needs a solution in perl, that is the reason why he wrote "using Perl script". Why he should change the language?

Comment: `-i` means to edit the file in place. Remove it if you want to write to standard output.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `-i` that means "in place", and so you don't need to redirect the output.  Either do this:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\"//g' file1
```

or this:

```
perl -p -e 's/\"//g' file1 > file2
```

But don't combine -i and redirection.

Comment: You don't need to escape the double quote.

Comment: still the above code is not working.. Redirection happens properly now.. but it is not removing the "..

Answer (score 0):

We need to give something like

```
perl -p -e 's/"^""//g' file1 > file2
```

if we are working on Windows, because "^" is the escape sequence for " in Windows.

Comment: The tag hints that this is on Unix, but the information is interesting.